# Is there something wrong with calling document.documentElement.classList.add in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am reading a lot that one should not manipulate the DOM at all in Angular, can someone explain to me why simply calling:

```
document.documentElement.classList.add('some-class')
```

is bad?

...or am I overthinking this? is this acceptable?

If it is wrong, what is the proper method?

**EDIT:**

To be exactly clear, what is the proper way to add a class to the `document.documentElement` as stated above.

`document.documentElement` = root element =  `<html>` element.

Comment: Angular manipulates the DOM on its own; you shouldn't write something that might collide with that I suppose

Comment: Angular will be unaware of the modification since it will be out of sync with its own shadow DOM.

Comment: Thank you, what is the correct way to add a class to the documentElement?

Comment: Check out my answer

Comment: OK, to be exactly clear, what is the proper way to add a class to the document.documentElement = ROOT element, i.e. the <html> element.

Answer (score 1):

**Explination**

As mentioned in the comments, manipulation like that will not be acknowledged by Angular, all manipulations should be done through Angular. This preserves how the DOM is built. This is a whole subject and one im not 100% with. An alternative would be to use [renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) provided by Angular along side a [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild).

One thing to remember is that sometimes the need to render apps in server or within a web worker arise where there is no DOM to directly interact with. Renderer2 removes any issues that can arise here by direct DOM interactions.

**Solution**

Apply a `#` to the element to use with the ViewChild.

```
<div #testDiv>
    some interesting content
</div>
```

In you controller.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

export class exampleComponent {
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

    public @ViewChild('testDiv') testDiv: ElementRef;

    public addClass(): void
    {
        this.renderer.setAttribute(this.testDiv.nativeElement, 'class', 'example-class');
    }

}
```

Could also use.

```
this.renderer.addClass(this.testDiv.nativeElement, 'example-class')
```

Here is some examples of using [renderer2](https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/).

Could probably get away with just using the ViewChild, but wanted to get renderer in as to show how to interact with the DOM.

```
this.testDiv.nativeElement.className = 'example-class';
```

Answer (score -1):

Angular has is own mechanism that deals with DOM manipulation.

You need to put id on your element (#myId) and get it using ViewChild('myId'). Let's see this in action:

.html file:

```
<div id="myIdName"></div>
```

.ts file:

```
import {AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
***

export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('myIdName') myId: ElementRef;

    addNewClass(className) {
        this.myId.nativeElement.classList.add(className);
    }
}
```

Or you can use Renderer2. You can look here:
https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not address document.documentElement = root element =  <html> element